# How can I increase a count by buying items in javascript?

Tags: javascript, game-development

I don't know how to word the question correctly, but I am trying to make a simple cookie clicker game in javascript and I am getting successful, and I made a buy grandma to increase the number of cookies per click. The way I am achieving this is by making a ton of if statements in js, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way of doing this. My code right now basically there is a cookie when you click the count goes up 1. You can buy a grandma and the js code automatically checks if you have bought a grandma by checking the multiplier innerHTML. Then it +1 on the count every time you click and increases more as you have a higher multiplier. So once again, how can I automate this in the function up() without using a bunch of if statements?

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="count">
    <div class="counter" id="counter">0</div>
    <div class="cookies">
      <img class="cookie" src="cookie.png" onclick="up()">
    </div>
    <div class="shop">
      <button onclick="buyGrandma()">Buy Grandma</button>
    </div>
    <div id="multiplier" class="multiplier">Multiplier: 1</div>
  </div>
  
  
  <script src="script.js"> </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and my JavaScript code is:

```
let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let count = 0;
let multiplier = 1;
let multiplierButton = document.getElementById("multiplier");
let multiplierCheck = document.getElementById("multiplier");

function up(){
  count += 1;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  if (multiplierCheck.innerHTML == "Multiplier: 2") {
    count +=1;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
  }
  if (multiplierCheck.innerHTML == "Multiplier: 3") {
    count +=2;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
  }
  if (multiplierCheck.innerHTML == "Multiplier: 4") {
    count +=3;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
  }
  if (multiplierCheck.innerHTML == "Multiplier: 5") {
    count +=4;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
  }
}

function buyGrandma(){
  if (count >= 30) {
    count -= 30;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
    multiplier += 1;
    multiplierButton.innerHTML = "Multiplier: " + multiplier;
  } else {
    alert("not enough cookies");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on SO, and top marks for the well written question.

As for an answer, you can simply use the variable `multiplier`:

```
function up(){
  count += multiplier + 1
  counter.innerHTML = count
}
```

Comment: @ThatGuyWhoNeedsHelp glad I helped! If that solved your problem please click the V sign on the left of my answer to validate it :)